# Zipping a folder in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, zip

Are there any libraries that work in Objective C for zipping entire folders (and decompressing them)? I have looked at some of them by searching but they look like they require adding files individually and some of them supposedly crash...

It looks like this library might work:
http://bitbucket.org/dchest/osxzip/overview

I don't know if it supports folders, however. Anyone know if it does or have any other libraries that support zipping folders? Even sample code for interacting with the command line libz would be fine with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSTask` to run the command line `ditto` program.  Be sure to look at the `ditto` man page for the right combination of flags to get Finder-compatible zipping.

Comment: Thanks for that link-- didn't know ditto could compress folders. After looking a few things over, I may end up wanting to use something command line anyways because I am currently deciding whether to go with Qt (for the cross platform, in which case I will use 7-zip on Windows through command line and ditto on Mac) or Objective C right now...

Answer (score 1):

According to this example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app you can get a NSData Object with the Zipped Data and then just write it with [data writeToFile....]

```
- (NSData *)exportToNSData {
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_docPath];
    NSFileWrapper *dirWrapper = [[[NSFileWrapper alloc] initWithURL:url options:0 error:&error] autorelease];
    if (dirWrapper == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating directory wrapper: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return nil;
    }   

    NSData *dirData = [dirWrapper serializedRepresentation];
    NSData *gzData = [dirData gzipDeflate];    
    return gzData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it is entirely possible that the directory I am zipping up has a massive number of files (10k+) and is over 200mb, so I am not sure if that would be the best approach (if it zips it in the RAM anyways). Would this be limited if I had that many files? (btw, I am not the one that came up with that directory structure and the whole 10k files thing :P )

Comment: I don't really know...I only used it for mac os x never on an iphone...but i think it should work.

Comment: To be picky, when people speak of "zipping" things, they usually mean PKZip format, which is probably not the same as what your code sample does.