# Is there an easy way to zip a file or a folder on Mac OS X using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a ZIP archive from a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928162/creating-a-zip-archive-from-a-cocoa-application)

Is there some open-source Objective C library I can use? Or can it be done without using an extra library?

Comment: [Zipping a folder in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236584/zipping-a-folder-in-objective-c) seems even more similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Objective-Zip. It uses ZLib and a project named MiniZip, and provides ObjC classes to deal with ZIP archives (read/write, password support, etc.).

Pretty efficient and easy to use.

http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

It also works for iOS, by the way...

Answer (score 1):

For files you can use the built-in libz (gzip) library.

This *could* also be used for recursively zipping folders of files (and other folders), however you would need to scan the directories, store the file/folder names and attributes in order to create a single stream of bytes, which isn't so simple (basically implementing UNIX `tar`).

Answer (score 0):

There’s a C library called zlib that can compress your files. [Here](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/) is a good tutorial on it, and you might want to check [this](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) out.

```
NSData* compressed = [myData zlibDeflate];
NSData* originalData = [compressed zlibInflate];
```